# Get the length of an animation from the Animator

Tags: unity

How do find the length of an animation that is included in the Animator attached to a GameObject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could find to do it by name is to iterate through the animations:

```
var animController = GetComponent<Animator>().runtimeAnimatorController;
var clip = animController.animationClips.First(a => a.name == "[The animation's name]");
Debug.Log(clip.length);
```

A constant time solution is to use an instance variable:

```
public AnimationClip clip;

void Start () {
    Debug.Log(clip.length);
}
```

Comment: If someone can provide a better answer, I'll change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
   float GetAnimationClipLength(Animator animator, int clipIndex){ 
   return animator.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips[clipIndex].length;
   }
```

clips indexes are in the order they were added to the animator controller, ex: index = 0 it's the very first clip added to the animator.

clips refer to the actual animation files, not the states of the animation state machine. Of course, if you put an index value either negative or greater than animationClips.Length -1( the number of clips in the animator controller) it will throw Array out of Range error.